# Python Pickle not saving entire object

Tags: python, object, serialization, pickle

I'm trying to pickle out a list of objects where the objects contain a list. When I open the pickled file I can see any data in my objects except from the list. I'm putting code below so this makes more sense.

Object that contains a list.

```
class TestPickle:
    testNumber = None
    testList = []

    def addNumber(self, value):
        self.testNumber = value
    def getNumber(self):
        return self.testNumber

    def addTestList(self, value):
        self.testList.append(value)
    def getTestList(self):
        return self.testList
```

This example I create a list of the above object (I'm adding one object to keep it brief)

```
testPKL = TestPickle()
testList = []
testPKL.addNumber(12)
testPKL.addTestList(1)
testPKL.addTestList(2)
testList.append(testPKL)

with open(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'test.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(testList, f)
```

Here is an example of me opening the pickled file and trying to access the data, I can only retrieve the testNumber from above, the testList returns a empty list.

```
pklResult = None
with open(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'test.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
    pklResult = pickle.load(f)

for result in pklResult:
    print result.getNumber() # returns 12
    print result.testNumber  # returns 12
    print result.getTestList() # returns []
    print result.testList      # returns []
```

I think i'm missing something obvious here but I'm not having any luck spotting it. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testNumber` and `testList` both are class attributes initially. `testNumber` is of immutable type hence modifying it create new instance attribute, But `testList` is of mutable type and can be modified in place. Hence modifying `testList` doesn't create new instance attribute and it remains as class attribute.
You can verify it -

```
print testPKL.__dict__
{'testNumber': 12}
print result.__dict__
{'testNumber': 12}
```

So when you access `result.testList`, it looks for class attribute `TestPickle.testList`, which is [] in your case.

## Solution

You are storing instance in pickle so use instance attribute. Modify `TestPickle` class as below -

```
class TestPickle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testNumber = None
        self.testList = []

    def addNumber(self, value):
        self.testNumber = value
    def getNumber(self):
        return self.testNumber

    def addTestList(self, value):
        self.testList.append(value)
    def getTestList(self):
        return self.testList
```